# Is it possible to rename fonts in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, fonts

I've accidently installed the wrong font as 'Helvetica'. I found a font called Helvetica online when I was looking at desktop customization, etc and I went and installed it. However, it's not actually Helvetica. I've now got a proper Helvetica font, but I can't seem to install it (it installs as Helvetica LT Std. Is there any way for me to delete 'Helvetica' and rename 'Helvetica LT Std' to 'Helvetica'?

Cheers,
Chintan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want rename Font name?
try this, maybe can help you;

1. Open the "Fonts" folder located in "C:\Windows\Fonts." -> Right-click on the font file and select "Rename." -> Type in the new name for the font, and then press "Enter." Enter your administrator password if you are prompted to.
2. You can use "Typograf" (http://www.neuber.com/typograph/), Navigate to the folder where font is located, select .ttf file, click Properties. Change font names (font family, full name, Postscript name etc) as required and click "Save as..." button.

Comment: -1 This shareware isn't worth the money, #crapware

Answer (score 3):

*Helvetica LT Std* is a particular version of Helvetica by Linotype. The font names you see displayed in programs are the fonts assigned by the foundry or font designer and should not be changed without good reason.

To change them, you have to actually edit the .ttf/.otf/etc. file, which would cause the font to no longer match up with the font names used on other computers. So if you were to transfer the font to another computer, you could end up overwriting the proper font on that computer, causing the same problem for someone else.

If you want a standard version of *Helvetica*, then you need to look for the [original PostScript Type 1 font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Core_Font_Set) published by Adobe. That and Apple's *Helvetica* (which comes with OS X) are the only two standard Helvetica fonts that are actually named "Helvetica".