# Installing Helvetica on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, fonts

I've installed Helvetica Neue fonts on my Windows. The problem is when websites use Helvetica or Helvetica Neue typeface, they almost exclusively do it simply using "Helvetica" or "Helvetica Neue" font-family. But In my windows, the Helvetica fonts are installed as a "HelveticaNeueLT Com 45 Lt" or "Helvetica LT Std" or similar extended name. I've tried to create my test page, and the browser renders the font properly only if I use the full font name. I'd like to know, how to make windows/browser display Helvetica properly?

Comment: Do you want YOUR computer to always use the specific Helvetica font when viewing pages, or are you designing a website you want to display in Helvetica on all computers?

Comment: Primarily the first one. I want my browser to display Helvetica or Helvetica Neue if the page uses it. But those web pages usually use only "Helvetica" or "Helvetica Neue", thus my browser doesn't recognize it and falls back to Arial even though I have Helvetica installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow these instructions on renaming fonts:

[Is it possible to rename fonts in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/426257/is-it-possible-to-rename-fonts-in-windows-7)

If you can get the HN typeface to be named correctly in the font catalog, they should appear on websites.

Comment: I've read about this method, but it 'feels dirty'. Quoting one of the answers from the link: "_Helvetica LT Std_ is a particular version of Helvetica by Linotype. The font names you see displayed in programs are the fonts assigned by the foundry or font designer and should not be changed without good reason." There has to be a proper installation method. How does one usually install Helvetica on Windows?

Comment: Oh, it's definitely dirty! It's something to do with the legacy licensing of Helvetica[Neue] and some exclusive rights. The LT versions are the best you can do, but without a dirty solution, it's not going to work on the web. Here's another thread on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657463/forcing-windows-to-display-helvetica-instead-of-arial

Comment: That said, while it would be a gross license violation, you might find  a way of copying the OSX Helvetica[Neue] fonts over to Windows. But you're on your own there, given the legal repercussions.

Comment: That means even when I have a license for the Helvetica fonts, I cannot use them to display text in web pages without license violation, because that would require editing them?

Comment: In a word, yes. The justification is that your LT fonts are likely for desktop use (which doesn't include browser). Not the answer you want to hear, but the most likely one. You may want to read through the LT license to make sure? More: It's important to note too that Helvetica Neue / Helvetica used on OSX is not the same as the LT version. They appear almost identical, but as far as the license and usage is considered, they are not.